# Toggling or accordian effect using Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

First of all i am new to angular, so i can't able to figure out how to achieve the below scenario.

On click I can able to show/Hide the relevant div for each row. But if the tooltip is open (let's say on 1st row it is opened) in one row and i am clicking on another row (let's say i am clicking on 3rd row ) then the open tooltip (from 1st row ) is  not hiding. Please help me on this.

Below is my code,

```
<div ng-repeat="breakdown in CallFullbreakdown" class="list-items-row">
    <div class="mob-number"><a data-ng-click="toggleDetails = !toggleDetails">{{breakdown.number}}</a></div>
    <div class="call-date"><a data-ng-click="toggleDetails = !toggleDetails">{{breakdown.dateandtime}}</a></div>
    <div class="call-cost text-align-right"><a data-ng-click="toggleDetails = !toggleDetails">£{{breakdown.cost}} <span class="chevron-style icon-up-chevron"></span></a></div>
    <!-- Start Call Breakdown Tooltip -->
    <div class="row position-relative call-breakdown" data-ng-show="toggleDetails">
        <span class="sprite arrow grey-arrow call-breakdown-arrow"></span>
        <div class="mob-number">
          <span class="bolder">Call type</span>
          <span>{{breakdown.callType}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="call-date">
          <span class="bolder">Destination</span>
          <span>{{breakdown.destination}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="call-cost text-align-right">
            <span class="bolder">Duration</span>
            <span>{{breakdown.duration}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Call Breakdown Tooltip -->
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: where is the tooltip div here ?

Comment: @Piyush.kapoor The div which is having " data-ng-show="toggleDetails" ". And also commented with  " Start Call Breakdown Tooltip ".

Answer (score 1):

Just switching one toggleDetails variable for all cannot close one while opening the other. Instead, create a reference to the breakdown curently opened in your controller.

Then, make toggleDetails a function taking the breakdown to toggle as an argument. That function can then control which breakdown is currently showing ist Details.

In your BreakdownController:

```
(...)
var activeBreakdown;
$scope.toggleDetails = function(breakdown) {
  if (breakdown === activeBreakdown) {
    // Breakdown is defined, so activeBreakdown must be as well
    activeBreakdown.showDetails = !activeBreakdown.showDetails;
  } else {
    if (activeBreakdown) {
      // Make sure the currently active breakdown is closed
      activeBreakdown.showDetails = false;
    }
    // If a new breakdown is selected, it needs to be opened
    breakdown.showDetails = true;
    // And put on activeBreakdown so it can be closed on the next toggle
    activeBreakdown = breakdown;
  }
};
(...)
```

html:

```
<div ng-repeat="breakdown in callFullBreakdown" class="list-items-row">
  <!-- Breakdown row stuff here... -->
  <!-- Start Call Breakdown Tooltip -->
  <div class="row position-relative call-breakdown" style="background-color: #a0a0a0" ng-show="breakdown.showDetails">
    <!-- Details/tooltip here -->
  </div>
  <!-- End Call Breakdown Tooltip -->
  <hr />
</div>
```

See this [Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/smAy16hgrXU90FIIEc9z?p=preview)

Also, to save on ng-clicks (and therefore also reduce the amount of potential error when changing something), see if you can wrap the row part (number, dateandtime, cost) in another element and put the ng-click there.

Comment: Great, Thanks @s-hoff , this is what I wanted. is not it possible without calling a click method in controller. we can't write any conditional statement in HTML itself?

Comment: None that I can think of (without making the ng-click expression unreadable), at least not if you want to be able to also close your details again (by clicking at the active breakdown a second time). Is there some technical reason why you cannot put it on the controller?

Comment: No there is not any technical reason for this, I just want to know if there is a way to achieve this with out controller. Well it is working fine. Thanks again @s-hoff.

Answer (score -1):

This is the first thing that bumped into my eyes:

```
data-ng-show="toggleDetails" data-ng-hide="!toggleDetails"
```

ng-show serves the purpose of showing AND hidding and element, depending on the boolean value of the variable assigned to it.
Using both on the same element is just a mess.

Also, you've spread the ng-show/hide all over the place. Couldn't it be done at the container level?

Ideally, you should give us a working sample on jsfiddle and we'll fix it from there.

Comment: Sorry i was trying to achieve  the above scenario. Thats y i had added. But right now i have modified my HTML. Please have a look.

Comment: Sorry i can't able to open fiddle in my network. Hence i have i have attached one screen shot.